# AspNetCore.OData 7.1.0 "$search" Query Option not working

Tags: search, .net-core, full-text-search, odata

I have created a .Net Core 2 API using OData 4.0 (part of AspNetCore.OData 7.1.0). 
Everything, except the "$search", seems to work.
The [documentation](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_The_$search_System) says it should work.

**The following requests I tested didn't work:**

- http://host/service/Products?$search=banana
- [http://host/service/Products?$search="banana"](http://host/service/Products?$search=%22banana%22)
- [http://host/service/$all?$search="banana"](http://host/service/$all?$search=%22banana%22)

error message:

```
{"message":"The query parameter 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: $search' is not supported.","exceptionMessage":"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: $search","exceptionType":"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException","stackTrace":"   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequest request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<OnActionExecuted>b__3(ODataQueryContext queryContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, IWebApiActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, Func`2 modelFunction, IWebApiRequestMessage request, Func`2 createQueryOptionFunction)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(Object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, IWebApiActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IWebApiRequestMessage request, Func`2 modelFunction, Func`2 createQueryOptionFunction, Action`1 createResponseAction, Action`3 createErrorAction)"}
```

**The following requests I tested worked:**

- http://host/service/$metadata/
- [http://host/service/Products?$filter=contains(name, "banana")](http://host/service/Products?$filter=contains(name,%20%22banana%22))

**My code:**

Configure app (defined in Startup.cs):

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // Cors
        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("*")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
        );

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", $"service/", GetEdmModel());
            routeBuilder.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
        });
    }
```

EdmModel (defined in Startup.cs):

```
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Product");
        builder.EntitySet<Producer>("Producer");
        builder.EntitySet<Consumer>("Consumer");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

.Net Core 2.2 Api "Get" (ProductsController.cs):

```
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<Product>))]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    [EnableQuery]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> Get()
    {
        var dbResponse = _context.Products.AsQueryable();
        return this.OK(dbresponse);
    }
```

Comment: Does it work if you send the $search HTTP request manually?  Maybe it's the server that doesn't support $search.

Comment: It seems it's indeed not supported for the .Net Web API.
I found someone stating this on this page: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527180/search-not-working-in-odata-web-api-2?answertab=votes#tab-top